# Dynamically creating file inside the deployed war

Tags: java, spring, weblogic

Inside web-inf folder I have added a new folder and my code dynamically creates a file when I have tested in my local.

But when the entire project is exported as war file and deployed inside server, the file is not getting created.While hitting the server,I am trying to access the file its throwing exception.

I am using weblogic server, spring project. Please suggest me some resolution.

Comment: It isn't a good practice to modify a WAR deployed on a server. You should try doing this outside of your WAR so this will be a bit more "production" complient.  
Moreover, when doing it on tests, you're not exactly doing it like it would be in a WAR

Comment: @DamCx what are the work arounds ? Should I put it in server leaf ? if yes then how to get server leaf's path ? How to do this outside war ?